# Magento admin panel inaccessible with no error (after server hang)

Tags: centos, magento

the server that a magento install was on crashed for (currently reason unknown) and now the backend is inaccessible. I either get no error or I get access denied. I am able to preform the password reset.

I have tried:

- clearing the browser cookies and cache
- clearing the session, tmp and cache folders in magento
- using the magento database repair tool - no errors were found
- creating a new user manually in the admin_users table (this gets access denied)
- rebooting the server again (last resort but still no)

The main admin user gets a redirect loop.

Any ideas are welcome, I am now stumped.

EDIT:I am really after any way to recover a magento admin login? or failing this any way to export the data (without exporting the bugged section)

Comment: Yikes, why does this sound like a server exploit to me? (server rebooting, admin access denied). If its true (that your system was compromised), it would also explain why you don't have access to it anymore.

Comment: By default Magento does not show errors. Have you tried putting your Magento into developer mode or ini_set('display_errors', 1); in your index.php file (find the if block and just put a "true ||" in there to force it)? I would start there to see if you get any errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have employed a hack in one of the core magento files detailed here: http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-admin-login-problem/

I have had to comment out lines in "app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php":
(please note this is for 1.6 - check link posted for advice on 1.4)

```
$cookieParams = array(
    'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
    'path'     => $cookie->getPath()//,
    //'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
    //'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
    //'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
);
```

also line 104 comment out :

```
//call_user_func_array('session_set_cookie_params', $cookieParams);
```

It seems to be when the server went down something happened to the session, as the new install also failed.

Comment: I'm setting up an in-house dev server and exactly this happened to me. Thanks for the hack.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your data by performing a database backup via cPanel or mysqldump via SSH access. Your hosting provider should be able to help you. Additionally, you can unzip the admin files from your Magento installed version. Download it to your computer and unzip the installation... then re-zip the folder for `app/design/adminhtml` ... upload and unpack this on your website in the proper place, and this will reinstall the PHP pages.

Double check the file `app/etc/local.xml` this usually has the database login stored in it.

Inside the mysql database for your magento installation, there is the table `core_config_data` and in it, some path values might interfere with using admin if intentionally set incorrectly:

```
mysql> select config_id, path, left(value,30) from core_config_data WHERE path LIKE '%admin%';
+-----------+-------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| config_id | path                                      | left(value,30)                 |
+-----------+-------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|        50 | dev/translate_inline/active_admin         | 0                              | 
|       220 | web/secure/use_in_adminhtml               | 0                              | 
|       687 | admin/startup/page                        | catalog/products               | 
|       690 | admin/security/use_form_key               | 0                              | 
|       691 | admin/security/use_case_sensitive_login   | 1                              | 
|       692 | admin/security/session_cookie_lifetime    | 36000                          | 
|       745 | admin/url/use_custom                      | 0                              | 
|       746 | admin/url/custom                          |                                | 
+-----------+-------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

Comment: I reinstalled magento with a fresh user accessing a fresh mysql schema. Same problem. I have since found a hack that is still implemented on the site - detailed below.