# Can't login Magento CMS

Tags: magento

I can't login on magento's admin

I've already done:

1. set a new password on the database with "UPDATE admin_user SET password=CONCAT(MD5('qXPASSWORD'), ':qX') WHERE username='admin';"
2. Restart nginx;
3. Restart php-fpm
4. Clear the browser cache;
5. Clear the magento caches: var/cache var/session /tmp/*
6. I've truncated the table core_session
7. I've done this [recomendations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272921/magento-admin-panel-inaccessible-with-no-error-after-server-hang)
8. It's set up correctly for the right database;

Is there anything else I should look into? What I'm missing?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you seeing an error message when you attempt to login?  If not, that usually indicates a problem setting up Magento's session (Magento passes error messages between page loads in the session).  This usually boils down to not able to set a cookie, which in turn boils down to

1. Your server time is too far off your client machine's time.  Check your server's time and timezone
2. You're using the `localhost` domain name with a webkit browser, which has some long standing issues with cookies and domain paths.  Use a fake TLD in your `hosts` file instead.

Comment: Hey Alan, on the end my problem here was a mounted drive. Thanks regardless, Your answer complements the check-list anyway. Cheers,